# See when the zip file has been zipped?

Tags: c#, file, zip, c#-ziparchive

I have googled without any luck.
My question is if there is a way to see when the file has been zipped? I am not asking for when the file has been created or modified rather to see when it has been zipped.

Is there a byte I can read from the zipped file somehow to find out this in code (C#)?

Comment: It does not make any sense to me..you mean when a file was added to a zip file?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell,that information is not stored in the zip file. The only info you can get is the last time that file inside the zip was modified. That datetime could or could not be the first time that file was included in the zip file.

If you want to get the last time the entry in the zip archive was changed, you can use the `ZipArchiveEntry.LastWriteTime` in the `System.IO.Compression` Namespace.

If you have any doubt of what info is availble in a zip file, you can check this wikipedia article : [Zip File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))